# How to read tables via defined names in xls file?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx, xls

I have an xls file which contains data in some cells and some tables. Tables have a defined name as shown in the image below.
There can be multiple tables in a sheet and the defined names for these tables are unique.

[image: Defined Table names]

I want to know how we can extract all the tables in the file using python.

I am currently able to do this for **.xlsx** files using `openpyxl` library but cannot find any library that does this for **.xls** files. I have looked into `xlrd` `xlsxwriter` and few other libraries.

**Alternate Solution** for this is to convert xls file to xlsx and the move ahead with the xlsx files.

However for some reason when converting the files from xls to xlsx only the cell data are copied and the table object is lost along with the defined-name for the table.

Comment: Have you had a look at pandas [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) function?

Comment: @Albo yes, it does not work

Comment: AFAIK xlrd can read defined names but not tables. You might be best off converting to XLSX in Excel and then using openpyxl.

Comment: @Albo `read_excel` uses xlrd internally and is only useful for getting the data, not the metadata, which is what's required here.

Comment: @Charlie Clark thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: @CharlieClark I am trying to convert xls into xlsx file however the tagging for the tables are getting lost when chnaging that.